# After upgrading to Sitecore 9.2 and SXA 1.9, why is Personalization is failing on all renderings?

Tags: sxa

After upgrading to Sitecore to 9.2 and SXA 1.9, personalisation on all renderings started to fail.

When the page loads for the first time, the item is rendered as expected, however, any subsequent page refreshes result in rendering item not being displayed.

```
public class MyComponentRepository : ModelRepository, IMyComponentRepository
{
    public override IRenderingModelBase GetModel()
    {
        MyComponentModel model = new MyComponentModel();
        FillBaseProperties(model);
        var checkDataSource = model.DataSourceItem;
        return model;
    }
}
```

I found **var checkDataSource = model.DataSourceItem;** was returning *null* on page refresh.

Comment: We have recently noticed that. Looks like there is a problem with local data sources and personalization. We have registered an issue for this in our backlog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I inspected **FillBaseProperties(model)** in the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.MVC dll:

```
IRenderingModelBase renderingModelBase = (IRenderingModelBase)model;
renderingModelBase.Item = this.Rendering.Item;
renderingModelBase.PageItem = this.PageContext.Current;
renderingModelBase.Rendering = this.Rendering;
renderingModelBase.DataSourceItem = this.Rendering.DataSourceItem;
```

I found that on first load, the **this.Rendering.DataSourceItem** was populated with Sitecore Item GUID, however, on subsequent page refreshes, it was null. The this.Rendering.DataSource was always populated with "local:/Data/myDataItem".

Sitecore Support have confirmed that this is a bug (reference number *362374*) and have suggested the following fix which resolved our issue:

Go to App_Config\Modules\SXA\Foundation\Sitecore.XA.Foundation.XConnectIntegration.config and **change** the following entry:

```
<mvc.customizeRendering>
 <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.SelectVariation, Sitecore.ContentTesting.Mvc']" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.LocalDatasources.Pipelines.CustomizeRendering.ResolveRenderingDatasource, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.XConnect.Integration" resolve="true" />
</mvc.customizeRendering>
```

To the following one:

```
 <mvc.customizeRendering>
   <processor patch:after="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Pipelines.Response.CustomizeRendering.Personalize, Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics']" type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.LocalDatasources.Pipelines.CustomizeRendering.ResolveRenderingDatasource, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.XConnect.Integration" resolve="true" />
 </mvc.customizeRendering>
```

Also make sure that your **web.config** has the following app setting with the value 'sxaxconnect':

```
    <add key="sxaxm:define" value="sxaxconnect" />
```

Comment: Adding this back in as an answer, as "Its a bug and here is the reference number" _is_ the answer for now.